# How to remove space from inside of a string in T-SQL

Tags: sql

Need to be able to remove spaces from the string. Spaces are not before starting the string or after the string, space is in the middle of a string. Below is an example of how the outcome should be.

Tried using `LTRIM()`, `RTRIM()`, `REPLACE()` none of them worked as an expected outcome.

Example string: `'KELL O G ATLAN TA MICROTE L INN'`

Expected Outcome string: `'KELLOG ATLANTA MICROTEL INN'`

Comment: How can we tell which spaces should be removed and which should be kept?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Are these spaces or some other white space characters? You might want to post your code so we know what exactly you tried that didn't work.

Comment: `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` remove whitespace from the beginning and end of a string, respectively. `REPLACE` will look through your input string for your matching string and replace it with the string you provide. With random spaces in your example string, you can either remove all the spaces, or you have to have more information of what the program is looking for.